# existe la estructura de datos Set de java para nodejs?

Tags: java, javascript, nodejs

estuve investigando sobre si existe alguna estructura similar a SET de Java, el cual no permite duplicados en la coleccion. necesito una estructura asi para eliminar duplicados de un archivo

hice este codigo pero inserta duplicados.

```
>  function reestructurar(dir,fileA){   var mySet = new Set();
>   read(`${dir}/training/${fileA}`, contentT => {
>                                   for (var i = 0, chunki = contentT.split('\n'), leni =chunki.length; i < leni; i++){
>                                   mySet.add(chunki);
>                                       
>                               }
>                                   console.log(mySet);
>                               });
> 
> }
```

lo modifique asi:

> var Set = require("collections/set");

```
function reestructurar(dir,fileA){
var set = new Set([]);
read(`${dir}/training/${fileA}`, contentT => {
                            for (var i = 0, chunki = contentT.split('\n'), leni =chunki.length; i < leni; i++){
                                set.add(chunki);

                            }
                                console.log(set);
                        });
```

}

no funciona, inserta de todo, necesito que inserte no repetidos

Answer (score 1):

Sí, Set y Map entre otros fueron añadidos a Javascript en su versión ES2015 (también conocida como ES6).

Su uso es sencillo:

```
var cartas = new Set()
cartas.add('♠')
cartas.add('♥')
cartas.add('♦')
cartas.add('♣')

cartas.has('♠') // true

cartas.has('joker') // false

cartas.size // 4

cartas.add('♣');

cartas.size // Sigue siendo 4 ya que ♣ ya pertenecía al set.
```

En [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set) tienes la documentación de Set.

Para poder utilizarlo necesitas que nodejs esté actualizado a versiones con el motor V8 para poder ejecutar ES2015 de forma nativa.

Para comprobar si tu versión de node lo soporta, visita [este otro enlace](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/).